# can clang static analyzer create .plist files in custom directory?

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

By default Clang-static-analyzer creates `.plist` files in current directory (from where the static analyzer is run).

Is there any way to make it generate `.plist` files in a custom directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the Clang Static Analyzer output its working from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371789/how-to-make-the-clang-static-analyzer-output-its-working-from-command-line)